# pyplot plotting with different shapes

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, shapes

I'm specifically trying to have one of my lines end sooner than the other. They are chronological (month by month and year over year).

```
months= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
pass_2015 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 134, 115, 185, 179, 147, 160, 126, 208, 48, 47, 50]
pass_2017 = [34, 106, 98, 162, 128, 166, 117, 123, 225, 161, 110, 100, 144, 53, 27, 10]
pass_2019 = [141,175,166,227,302,302,314]
plt.plot(months, pass_2015, color='gray')
plt.plot(months, pass_2017, color='green')
plt.plot(months, pass_2019, color='blue')
```

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: pass_2019 produces an error rather than a line that simply stops when the data stops.

Comment: Also, what is `months`? We can't run your code without it.

Comment: Sorry I'm new. Should I answer here? months= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16] .(Also just added into code above)

Comment: ok, the problem is that `months` and `pass_...` don't always have the same length. You could take slices of month, `e.g. month[:len(pass_2019)]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
months= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
pass_2015 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 134, 115, 185, 179, 147, 160, 126, 208, 48, 47, 50]
pass_2017 = [34, 106, 98, 162, 128, 166, 117, 123, 225, 161, 110, 100, 144, 53, 27, 10]
pass_2019 = [141,175,166,227,302,302,314]
plt.plot(months, pass_2015, color='gray')
plt.plot(months, pass_2017, color='green')
plt.plot(months[:len(pass_2019)], pass_2019, color='blue')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!

Comment: If that's the green check mark then I just did. If it's not then please let me know! Thanks again.