# How to display multiple plots with different shapes with Streamlit?

Tags: python, streamlit

I am trying to display multiple plots with different shapes. However, I got an error message `ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (10000,) and (5000,)`

Actually, they have different shapes and must be displayed in different plots.

**Expectation**: Display 2 charts for `signals` and `resampled_signal`

Here is my code:

```
time = np.arange(signals.size) / fs_target
fig1 = plt.figure()
fig2 = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)

ax1.plot(time, signals, color='blue', marker='o')
ax2.plot(time, resampled_signal, color='blue', marker='o')
st.pyplot(plt)
```

I followed the idea in [python - pyplot plotting with different shapes - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53220678/pyplot-plotting-with-different-shapes), but the error will come when the `st.pyplot(plt)` is executed.

Comment: The size of your `resampled_signal` should have the same size with your `time`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Regarding the business, the time remains stable but the signal is recalculated based on the sample rate. That leads to the different lengths (number of samples).

That's why I have the `resampled_signal` and `signals` at the same time, but different length. And I tried to show the difference by displaying the plots

Comment: What is the length or size of your `resampled_signal` and what is the length or size of your `time`?